# Why is my Question "on hold"

Tags: discussion

I have added a question

it was put on hold as "unclear what you're asking"
I have Edited my question

"If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please **edit your question**."

I simplified it and wrote it in correct English

Why is it still on hold?

the question is simple, when I log in with root user in MATE there are no desktop icons.
how to get them back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editing your question does not automatically cause it to reopen. It is put into a review queue, which is tended by other members of the site with a certain threshold of reputation. These members can vote to reopen (if the edit addresses the concerns) or leave closed (if the edit does not). It sometimes takes some time for questions with good edits to be reopened.